# How to reject any incoming call when I have already detected it

Tags: android

Application detects incoming calls and displays a toast when they come. The inner class `CallStateListener` is responsible for detecting the call:

```
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone

                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

but now just after a Toast is shown I would like to cancel/reject this incoming call(any). 
How to perform cancelling this incoming call?

The full class looks like that:

```
package com.example.a;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CallHelper {

    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls.
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone

                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
/*  public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }*/

}
```

EDIT:

[image]

**EDIT2**
Maybe I lack permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <service
            android:name=".CallDetectService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

**UPDATED CLASS**

package com.example.a;

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CallHelper {

    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls.
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 try{
                        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  

                        telephonyService = (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                        telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;

        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    /*
     * public void stop() { tm.listen(callStateListener,
     * PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
     * ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver); }
     */

}
```

**EDIT 3**
Link to project: http://www.speedyshare.com/ccY6T/A1.zip

Answer (score 6):

**Import these...**

```
  import java.lang.reflect.Method;
  import android.app.Activity;  
  import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
  import com.android.internal.telephony.*;
```

**Use this code to reject the phone call.**

```
 try{
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  
    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
    telephonyService.silenceRinger();
    telephonyService.endCall();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      // Some problem occurred while accessing private API
    // TODO: do whatever error handling you want here  

}
```

**Add these permissions into Manifest file.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

The **com.android.internal.telephony** is not part of the Android SDK.
You can get this Java file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java).

**Note:**

Here we uses **Java reflection**.These methods are there, but they are marked as **"private"**. Using reflection, we can get lots of information about classes, even the information that is considered **"private"**. Since this is an **"unsupported API"** it may not work on all devices and it may be changed in a future release of Android

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that I do not know what type should be `telephonyService`. By looking on your code it should be `ITelephony` because you cast it, but this class/interface can't be found.

Comment: I copied updated code(please look at edit in OP, I edited it too). The problem is there is no: `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony`. There is only `com.android.internal.util`.

Comment: "The import com.android.internal.telephony.*; cannot be resolved". I get this.

Comment: Thanks now there is no errors. I pasted updated code into EDIT2. The problem is that the phone does not rejects the call. The Android version is 4.2

Comment: Oh I added Manifest to show permissions I used also I will post my project in EDIT 3.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
not allowed permission