# how to Import com.android.internal.telephony

Tags: android

How do I Import the following? I have tried them this way but nothing is happening . Please help?

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.AppInterface;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.LaunchBrowserMode;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Menu;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Item;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Input;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.ResultCode;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatCmdMessage;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatCmdMessage.BrowserSettings;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatCmdMessage.SetupEventListSettings;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.Log;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatResponseMessage;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.TextMessage;
import com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccRefreshResponse;
import com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.IccCardStatus.CardState;
import com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneConstants;
import com.android.internal.telephony.TelephonyIntents;
import com.android.internal.telephony.IccCardConstantsa;
import com.android.internal.telephony.uicc.UiccController;
import com.android.internal.telephony.GsmAlphabet;
import com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatService;
```

Answer (score 0):

These classes are hidden. You can not use directly. I guess **reflection** is the one solution.

Answer (score 0):

As `com.android.internal.telephony` is falls under internal(or hidden) APIs of Android, you can't directly import it. But there are ways to work with them though. I'd suggest you to go over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24580712/2709580) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20099845/2709580) to get an idea on how to work with telephony through reflection.

Comment: how do I for example do this

Comment: Item item = getSelectedItem(position);