# Is it possible to create Android system app to grant system permissions, precisely MODIFY_PHONE_STATE?

Tags: android, permissions

I would like to create application which can reject incoming calls(EDIT 2 in that topic): [How to reject any incoming call when I have already detected it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580223/how-to-reject-any-incoming-call-when-i-have-already-detected-it/24580252?noredirect=1#comment38077652_24580252)

The case is that I **probably** need permission: `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`. Which can be granted only for system apps. But there are other callers/phone application which can block calls, or replace default Dialer so it can be done somehow. I will install this application only on my phone.

**To conclude:** Is there possibility of creating application which will have status of Android system app to grant necessary permissions?

I have found this: `To get these permissions, the application must be signed with the key which used to sign the platform. This may be different for manufacturers. So it practically not possible to get these permissions granted to a user application.`
How to do it?

Comment: Are you willing to root your phone to make this application work?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I want it to work at least on  my phone.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Works anywhere. Działa tak jak powinno.

Answer (score 3):

System-level permissions are not exactly the same as signature-level permissions.

- System-level permissions can only be obtained for system apps. System apps are jus those that are installed in a particular location (under `/system`). However you cannot normally place apps there, unless the device is rooted or has a custom recovery.
- Signature-level permissions are only granted to apps signed with the same key as the app that defines the permission.

So, to get a system-level permission, you can develop your application normally, but you cannot actually install it without following a more complicated procedure. Check [this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/), for example.

As for `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` in particular, it's marked as [`signatureOrSystem`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15022) or [the declaration](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4ece2086f3b7060edc4b93a12f04c9af648867a/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml). So it's a system-level permission.

> A permission that the system grants only to applications that are in
>   the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificate
>   as the application that declared the permission.

Comment: Is MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is system or signature level permission? If signature I have to know key of Dialer?

Comment: Ok. The `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is not necessary. `PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS` is enough and it can be granted to any app. The weird thing is that Eclipse does not find it and you have to type it letter by letter.