# Android reject incoming call

Tags: java, android, phone-call, callblocking

In my android project(with target sdk version 23), I want reject incoming call. 
I know that there are a lot of question about this, in particular

1 [How to import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony to the Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580508/how-to-import-com-android-internal-telephony-itelephony-to-the-android-applicati)

2 [How to Reject a call programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347871/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-in-android)

3 [How to reject any incoming call when I have already detected it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580223/how-to-reject-any-incoming-call-when-i-have-already-detected-it/24580252?noredirect=1#comment38077652_24580252)

In the first one link, the suggest solution is use reflection on the interface `ITelephony` because it's an internal interface. But this solution use `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission, which can only be granted to system apps so it won't work anyway.

From second and third link, I understand that solution is copy `ITelephony` from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.java#ITelephony.getRadioAccessFamily%28int%29) then put it in a new package of `com.android.internal.telephony` in my solution.
The problem is that in this interface there are a lot of problem about find of class `android.telephony.RadioAccessFamily` (*error cannot find symbol class `RadioAccessFamily`*), that class is in [platform framework base of android](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/RadioAccessFamily.java).

Any idea for resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you post your relevant code, I don;t see the need for RadioAccessFamily. Also try the tutorial at http://www.emoticode.net/android-sdk/block-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-programmatically.html

Comment: the code is the interface  ITelephony not my android code.

The tutorial is old, 2 years ago, I use like target sdk version 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. For others interested, here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065415/1970301) it is:

create aidl folder in main folder.

create package com.android.internal.telephony in aidl folder

create a aidl file in package:

```
interface ITelephony {      

    boolean endCall(); 
    void answerRingingCall();      

}
```

for the code about end call see the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065415/1970301).

and it's not necessary add the permission

> android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE